# Gnome Terminal---hide the tilde files produced by Emacs

Tags: emacs, gnome-terminal

Editing text file using Emacs will make Emacs make a companion file for its own purpose.

For example, after first editing a file called `test.c`, Emacs will leave a file called `test.c~` in the same directory. This can be a little annoying when visualizing all files cluttered with the `~` files in a console

Any way to get rid of seeing these `~` files in a console, like the Gnome Terminal?

**Update**

Thanks to @don_crisst's comment below:

use `ls -B` to hide the ~ files when displaying file names. The command line switches, `-B` or `--ignore-backups`, do not list implied entries ending with ~.

Comment: Is that when using `ls` ? You can use `ls -B`. `-B` or `--ignore-backups` = `do not list implied entries ending with ~`

Comment: There should be a law that emacs users have to clean up after themselves or configure it to not do this, honestly.

Comment: You can configure emacs to put these files in a different location (backup-dir, autosave-dir, or something like that).

Comment: Possibly useful: [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151946/486504) (has instructions both for configuring where the backup files are stored, and disabling file save backups entirely)

Comment: Please note, that configuring emacs to save backup files in a different directory can pose security risks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ls -B` to hide the ~ files when displaying file names. The command line switches, `-B` or `--ignore-backups`, do not list implied entries ending with ~.

Comment: If you are using Bash, see also the `FIGNORE` environment variable, which allows you to exclude files from tab completion by pattern matching.  There is also `GLOBIGNORE` for excluding files from glob (wildcard) expansion.

Comment: Eye-opening comment. Thanks. @tripleee

Comment: does not work on vanilla osx, where -B has a different meaning (non-printable characters).